# Read-write problem with my HDD

Tags: read-only, chown

I have problem with my HDD, all partitions are read only. I try this 
`sudo chown -R user:group /home/marcus/{Storage,Windows}` 
 but it doesn't work.

Comment: Try `sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /home/marcus/{Storage,Windows}`.

Comment: If you're on a current version of Ubuntu, and your disk device is `/dev/sdX`, then `journalctl /dev/sdX` will show you informative messages that will let you figure out why your partitions are read-only. What type of filesystem is on the disk, NTFS?

Comment: Don't ever recursive chown ~/.  It's a bad idea, and it breaks things.

Comment: Your filesystem is probably corrupt; run chkdsk/scandisk from Windows.

Comment: the read only partition are NTFS